# Highchart Scatter Series must appear in front of the column series, but if it contains more than 5k records, it appears at the back of column series

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng, angular2-highcharts

Chart as three columns series with stacking on top and one scatter series with over 5k records. So, in the front view, we need to see the scatter first, followed by the subsequent column series. It works perfectly with less than 5k records, but if there are more than 5k, the columns chart falls back.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-8xhbqo?file=index.js,index.html,package.json)

[image: Actual Image]

Expecting Series must appear in front of the column series

[image: Expected Image]

Answer (score 0):

For large amounts of data you can use [Highcharts Boost module](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module), add to this script to your project:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/boost.js"></script>
```

Blog article explain how to work with boost module:

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/boost-module